# eval() behavior with input()

Tags: python, eval

I have a beginner's question.

```
>>> eval("1 + 2 * 3")
7
```

Makes sense.
But why is it that

```
>>> eval(input())
"1 + 2 * 3"
'1 + 2 * 3'
```

I literally see no difference between the manually inserted string and the string given to the function in the shell? Why or how does the interpreter evaluate it differently? The previous questions on eval I found here didn't really cover my problem. I want to understand what's happening behind the scenes...

Comment: Leave the quotes out of your input and it will work.  Eval is trying to "eval" them as well.

Comment: But then I wouldn't enter a string anymore but an integer, right? This would change the whole thing

Comment: `input()` always returns a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `input()`, it returns the entire input line as a string, it doesn't parse it like program code. So the quotes are included literally.

So when you enter quotes in the input response, it's equivalent to doing:

```
eval('"1 + 2 * 3"')
```

You need the quotes when you're calling `eval()` manually, because the quotes are part of the syntax for literal strings. But they're not actually part of the string.

Comment: Ok I think I got it now, Thanks to you and chrisz

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

**eval(input(r""))**

```
>>> eval(input(r""))
1 + 2 * 3

O/P: 7
```